# Php code protection libraries

Tags: php

There are many code protection libraries in php, however they require installation of additional php modules, which I can not afford because the application will be running on servers I do not own. So I thought I could make my own.

What I want to do:

```
$source = file_get_contents("encryptedPhpFile.php");
$source = decrypt($source, "mySecretKey");
//$source now contains decrypted source code which needs to be included

//I cant use eval($source); because that code also contains 
//html/css/opening and closing php tags ... which eval() does
//not know how to render

//I cant write the source into temporary file and then include
//that file because as soon as I write decrypted source to a disk,
//it is exposed and it can be copyed
```

What can I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: nothing reliable. Your only option is to eval or write a file with the source and include that. However, this isn't "secure" in any way. As all someone would have to do is `echo $source` after the `decrypt` call and they have your whole source.

Comment: The title doesn't really aptly describe the question. Could you improve it?

Comment: Why do you need to "protect" your code anyways? People can't download your php script source unless the whole server is compromised, at which point I doubt any protection would help.

Comment: if the code is running on my server, i want to be able to see it. I would never run anything 'encoded' (not that that can't be undone). what problem are you actually trying to solve here??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These libraries are modules for a reason. You will not be able to fully simulate them in "code space". Your attempts will be clumsy (not your fault) and make your codebase far less pleasing/maintainable.

You should instead focus your efforts on obtaining permission to install them, migrating to a host that lets you control your server to a useful degree, or getting your own server up and running.

Answer (score 6):

Again and again.
We cannot protect PHP source code. PHP was not meant to be 'protected'. Even compiling code to binary is prone to reverse engineering. In your example, when you `decrypt` source with secret key (how secret - there he is) you do what? Eval it? Replace eval with echo.

Write license & do legal job with lawyer. Organize business model so your customers would want to pay you so they could get updates & support.

Regarding code protection libraries (paid ones): there are free online services that automatically decode them for you...